# Fundamental similarity between resistor, capacitor, and inductors?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, inductor

I notice that resistors, capacitors, and inductors share some fundamental similarities: for example, the way you compute their values in series and in parallel is extremely similar.

Likewise, it seems that if you said that resistors have a time constant of zero, they also follow the e^x timing law that inductors and capacitors share.

Is there some real fundamental similarity here (like an interface that all of these components satisfy) that causes this? Or is it just happenstance?

Comment: The similarity is that all these parts are linear on the level you are talking about, therefore share similar mathematics.

Comment: yeah, they all can be represented by a complex impedance that is either real or purely imaginary. But I guess you know that already – that's literally first lesson in the first lecture on most EE programs...

Comment: FWIW many physical phenomena can be described using very similar math, while mostly unrelated otherwise

Answer (score 3):

They can all be treated as impedance in the complex space:

$$
Z_L = j \omega L  
$$
$$
Z_C = \frac{1}{j \omega C}
$$
$$
Z_R = R
$$

You can then treat them (the complex impedance or Z) like you do resistors. You can do this because the circuit elements are linear and the equations are linear for a given frequency. (The supplies can also be converted to the complex space and you can analyze an AC circuit like you would in DC).